# ¿cómo hacer seed a una tabla en laravel con relaciones a sí misma?

Tags: laravel, relaciones, migration, seed, factory

Tengo esto en mi tabla **cows**:

```php
Schema::create('cows', function (Blueprint $table) {
    $table->bigIncrements('id');
    $table->string('name')->nullable(false);
    $table->char('gender',1)->nullable(false);
    $table->unsignedBigInteger('cow_father_id')->nullable();
    $table->foreign('cow_father_id')->references('id')->on('cows')->onDelete('cascade')->onUpdate('cascade');
    $table->unsignedBigInteger('cow_mother_id')->nullable();
    $table->foreign('cow_mother_id')->references('id')->on('cows')->onDelete('cascade')->onUpdate('cascade');
    $table->timestamps();
});
```

y esto en mi modelo **Cow**:

```php
protected $guarded = [];

public function father()
{
    return $this->belongsTo(self::class, 'cow_father_id');
}

public function mother()
{
    return $this->belongsTo(self::class, 'cow_mother_id');
}

public function children()
{
    return $this->hasMany(self::class, 'cow_father_id')->orWhere('cow_mother_id', $this->id);
}
```

**¿Cuál sería la factory y el database seeder para esta tabla, teniendo en cuenta sus relaciónes consigo misma?**

Tener en cuenta que los padres deben tener genero masculino (**gender**=**M**) y las madres femenino (**gender**=**F**)

lo que he logrado por mi cuenta no satisface mis necesidades, esta es mi **CowFactory**

```php
use App\Cow;
use Faker\Generator as Faker;

Cow::create([
    'name' => 'adan',
    'gender' => 'M'
]);

Cow::create([
    'name' => 'eva',
    'gender' => 'F'
]);

$factory->define(Cow::class, function (Faker $faker) {
    return [
        'name' => $faker->name,
        'gender' =>  $faker->randomElement(['M', 'F']),
        'cow_father_id' => Cow::where('gender','M')->get()->random()->id,//Cow::all()->random()->id,
        'cow_mother_id' => Cow::where('gender','F')->get()->random()->id,//Cow::all()->random()->id,
    ];
});
```

como pueden ver, he generado un adan y una eva sin padre ni madre

y esto es lo que hay en mi **DatabaseSeeder**

```php
public function run()
    {
        factory(Cow::class, 20)->create()->each(function($c) {
            dump($c->father()->first()->name.','.$c->mother()->first()->name);
            //$c->mother()->save(factory(Cow::class)->make());
            //$c->father()->save(factory(Cow::class)->make());
        });
    }
```

Logro imprimir el nombre del padre y la madre asignado, pero no logro que de manera automatica las vacas que se van generando puedan ser padres o madres de las demas vacas, solo logre que todos tengan los mismos padres.

quiero una **DatabaseSeed** que me genere estas vacas con diferentes padres y madres. que se puedan repetir(varias vacas con mismo padre y madre, mas no todos) e incluso que estos puedan ser nulos

pero si me carga un id de padre o madre que este si exista en mi DB.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Se me ocurre que a la definición de la factory, la puedes hacer con la información básica de un `Cow` sin padre ni madre:

```
$factory->define(Cow::class, function (Faker $faker) {
    $gender = $faker->randomElement(['M', 'F']);
    return [
        // información básica de un Cow sin padre ni madre
        'name' => $faker->name,
        'gender' =>  $gender,
    ];
});
```

Y definir también un [state](https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/database-testing#factory-states) que te permita definir los atributos `cow_father_id` y `cow_mother_id`:

```
$factory->state(Cow::class, 'child', function (Faker $faker) {
    // A estos le asignamos un padre y una madre random
    $father = Cow::where('gender','M')->inRandomOrder()->first();
    $mother = Cow::where('gender','F')->inRandomOrder()->first();
    return [
        'cow_father_id' => $father->id ?? null,
        'cow_mother_id' => $mother->id ?? null,
    ];
});
```

Luego creas una cantidad x de Cow sin padres, y otra cantidad x usando el state para que sean hijos de alguno de los creados anteriormente:

```
$parents = factory(Cow::class, 10)->create();
$childs = factory(Cow::class, 100)->states('child')->create();
```

---

O para tener mayor control, puedes definir también states para crear un macho o una hembra

```
$factory->define(Cow::class, function (Faker $faker) {
    return [
        // información básica de un Cow sin género, padre ni madre
        'name' => $faker->name,
    ];
});
$factory->state(Cow::class, 'male', function (Faker $faker) {
    return [
        'gender' =>  'M',
    ];
});
$factory->state(Cow::class, 'female', function (Faker $faker) {
    return [
        'gender' =>  'F',
    ];
});
$factory->state(Cow::class, 'child', function (Faker $faker) {
    $gender = $faker->randomElement(['M', 'F']);
    $father = Cow::where('gender','M')->inRandomOrder()->first() ?? factory(Cow::class)->states('male')->create();
    $mother = Cow::where('gender','F')->inRandomOrder()->first() ?? factory(Cow::class)->states('female')->create();
    return [
        'gender' =>  $gender,
        'cow_father_id' => $father->id,
        'cow_mother_id' => $mother->id,
    ];
});
```

Luego creas una cantidad x de hijos, y en el caso de no existir padre o madre, que cree un macho o hembra en el momento:

```
$childs = factory(Cow::class, 100)->states('child')->create();
```