# Crear un factory dependiendo de las llaves foreaneas existentes

Tags: php, laravel

es que quiero crear un factory que solo obtenga los numeros de otra tabla o sea unas llaves foraneas.

```
 public function definition()
    {
        return [
            'Categorias_id' => $this->faker->numberBetween(1, 10),
            'titulo' => $this->faker->name,
            'contenido' => $this->faker->text,
        ];
    }
```

Comment: [Esto](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/516693/c%c3%b3mo-hacer-seed-a-una-tabla-en-laravel-con-relaciones-a-s%c3%ad-misma/516722#516722) es un poco más complejo de lo que estás preguntando, pero básicamente lo que puedes hacer es obtener un registro random de la base de datos para que use la factory

Comment: Si eso hice ya pongo la solución

Answer (score 1):

Es facil realmente,  se hace randomElement lo que hace esta función es escoger un dato del arreglo ejemplo [1,2,3,4] escoge un valor de esos 4, y para sacar el arreglo se hace una consulta a la BD.

```
class PostsFactory extends Factory
    {
        /**
         * Define the model's default state.
         *
         * @return array
         */
        public function definition()
        {
            return [
                'Categorias_id' => $this->faker->randomElement(\App\Models\Categorias::pluck('id')->toArray()),
                'titulo' => $this->faker->name,
                'contenido' => $this->faker->paragraph(40),
            ];
        }
    }
```